# Google BigQuery DML Update query on rows still in the Streaming buffer

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I've been recently trying to come up with a retry mechanism for Google's Big  Query streaming api for running DML queries with UPDATE statement over Rows that could sometimes still be in the Streaming Buffer. As these rows have not yet been exported to the table, BI's api forbids UPDATE or DELETE statements to be ran on them. As I understand there is no way to manually flush the Streaming Buffer yourself.

My question is, is there a way or a good practice for a call with some sort of retry mechanism that will do this for the announced possible 90 minute of wait time (that the rows can be in the buffer)?

Comment: I am having the same problem, and would love an official answer from either Pavan or Elliott if they see this. We need to address this questions, it's not maintainable on some large tables.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend copy data from table where streaming occurs to another table on which DML could be run without any limitations. This another permanent table could be created with [jobs.insert API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results)
You need to treat this permanent table as source of true, on original table you could [enable table's expiration time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time) or [partition expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration) depending on your needs and coping frequency.
Now when you have permanent table you could run some other processing on that data or generate report etc.
Drawback of above is that you could have some late data anyway you should fetch/copy and deduplicate reasonable window of data to permanent table to guarantee the most recent data

I assume that streaming to your table could be run again and again, so you could theoretically be never able to run you DML as streaming buffer could be never empty.

Anyway if you still need run some retry mechanism try using something like https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility

Comment: I'd like to hear the continuation of your process. You copy the data to a new table, you run DML, but how do you continue? what do you do now with the table and copy?

Comment: table is left as it is (but it could be like that as there is retention period for that table, copy (with some transformations) is treated as valuable table for business purposes

Comment: I am not following you. When you have a DML you need that data persistet on a dataset which is actively queried in a report/dashboard. So you must somehow write back to the original table, or shift the reporting tool tovards the new table. Lots of issues to deal with and it's not explaining. Your answer is not complete.

Comment: I edited answer to consider your remarks, thanks for them

Comment: So your suggestion is to try and maintain something like a cqrs pattern. Tho isn't this somewhat of an excessive duplication of the tables? I would have to double persist every row twice in order to be able to run the DML query.

About the stream never being empty, the rows that cannot be queried are only the ones still in the stream. There are workers which constantly  read a given table's buffer, and write them out into columnar format. When written they are marked as garbage and removed from the buffer. I do not think that an always "full" buffer would be the problem here.